# Dynamically get value ie scrollTop() and store in an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, scrolltop

I'm trying to get dynamic values ie scrollTop() and and text() - store them in an array and then use them later in a scroll event. So far i have this, which only seems to be pushing the first value. Im sure there is some other super efficient way of doing this using a lot less code, but i'm pretty new to this and am just trying to understand why it isn't working. any help would be hugely appreciated! Sami.

```
var $titleName = [];
var $titlePosition = [];

$('#section-title').each(function () {
    $titleName.push($(this).text());
});

$('#section-title').each(function () {
    $titlePosition.push($(this).offset());
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    windowScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (windowScroll >= $titlePosition[0].top) {
        $tooltip.text($titleName[0]);
    }

    if (windowScroll >= $titlePosition[1].top - 100) {
        $tooltip.text($titleName[1]);
    }

    if (windowScroll >= $titlePosition[2].top - 100) {
        $tooltip.text($titleName[2]);
    }

    if (windowScroll >= $titlePosition[3].top - 100) {
        $tooltip.text($titleName[3]);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/sTNJM/

Comment: `$('#section-title').each...` If there are more than one `id="section-title"` elements, you need to switch those to `.section-title` classes. Only one `id` is allowed. Which would perhaps explain why only one element is getting changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.section-title` to class, as ID's are unique, use `$.map` for the arrays, and each to iterate and do the if conditions :

```
var elem           = $('.section-title'),
    $titleName     = $.map(elem, function(el,i) { return $(el).text(); }),
    $titlePosition = $.map(elem, function(el,i) { return $(el).offset().top; });

$(window).on('scroll',function() {
    var windowScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

    $.each($titlePosition, function(i, pos) {
        var pad = i>0 ? 100 : 0;
        if ( windowScroll >= (pos - pad) ) $tooltip.text($titleName[i]);   
    });
});
```

Comment: Where does `$tooltip` come from? And you have a stray `,` at the end of the variable list.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - how should I know where `$tooltip` comes from? Fixed the comma, thanks!

Comment: I figured it was some kind of scrollspy setup, so I assumed `$tooltip` was a header: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/pejK5/1/ Also, in the `$titlePosition` `$.map()`, the `this` should be `el`.